# dpdk rte_eth_rx_burst can't receive pkts And Got imissed inc

Tags: dpdk

when another process mmap and read the pci resource file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjQv7.png)

Env:
Eth X520 ixgbe Driver
DPDK 19.11
OS centos 7

Comment: please rephrase the question clearly. Based on the image (code) there are no DPDK API exercised. Also at a time only Primary and Secondary process can share the same NIC resoruce. Marking as `need more data` as the question or intention is not clear.